# Django TestCase crashes

Tags: django

I've created quite a few TestCases for my apps and everything was working as expected so far, recently I get this error Message when trying to run any TestCase (SimpleTestCase works fine, since it doesnt create any DB Objects, at least thats my theory).

Example:

```
# # pages/tests.py

from django.test import SimpleTestCase, TestCase
from non_voice.models import Product


class HomePageTests(SimpleTestCase):

    def test_home_page_status_code(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

class ProductTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        Product.objects.create(product='test', product_name='test', header_text='test', language_code='DE')

    def test_text_content(self):
        product = Product.objects.get(id=1)
        expected_object_name = f'{product.product}'
        self.assertEquals(expected_object_name, 'test')
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/EDR_ICT/.virtualenvs/WSx_Dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/EDR_ICT/.virtualenvs/WSx_Dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/EDR_ICT/.virtualenvs/WSx_Dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/EDR_ICT/.virtualenvs/WSx_Dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/EDR_ICT/.virtualenvs/WSx_Dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/EDR_ICT/.virtualenvs/WSx_Dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 53, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/EDR_ICT/.virtualenvs/WSx_Dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 684, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
  File "/EDR_ICT/.virtualenvs/WSx_Dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 606, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/EDR_ICT/.virtualenvs/WSx_Dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 156, in setup_databases
    test_databases, mirrored_aliases = get_unique_databases_and_mirrors(aliases)
  File "/EDR_ICT/.virtualenvs/WSx_Dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 272, in get_unique_databases_and_mirrors
    (connection.settings_dict['NAME'], set())
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

DataBase Setup for Dev (works in normal operation):

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'NAME': 'WSX_NV_AUT',
            'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
            'HOST': f'{db_server}, {db_port}',  # MS SQL Driver needs the port in the hostname
            'USER': db_user,
            'PASSWORD': db_password,
            'PORT': {db_port},

            'OPTIONS': {
                'driver': "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
            }
        }
    }
```

I haven't changed anything I can think of, DB drivers are the same, django version and libraries unchanged etc? Someone got any ideas?

Comment: It seems your `DATABASES` settings variable has some issues. Can you add the `DATABASES` value that used while running the tests?

Comment: @JPG Added it above, if I print my settings.DATABASES in the Test I get the correct entry interestingly enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'PORT': {db_port}` is causing this error because you aim to create a set/dictionary with only a key and no value. This is probably a leftover or an oversight when working with f-strings.

This will resolve this error:

```py
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'NAME': 'WSX_NV_AUT',
            'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
            'HOST': f'{db_server}, {db_port}',  # MS SQL Driver needs the port in the hostname
            'USER': db_user,
            'PASSWORD': db_password,
            'PORT': db_port, # note the removed {}

            'OPTIONS': {
                'driver': "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, really an oversight, I don't get why this doesn't lead to any issues when running the Application? :)